# Filtering Json with .map

Tags: javascript, typescript, youtube-api, ionic3

I'm trying to filter this .json in order not to show private videos.
It's for a app of a youtube channel.
There are some videos that are private and I don't want to show them in the app. 
I need help filtering the .json

Currently it's returning an empty json. if I remove the .map it returns the complete list of videos with the privete ones.

```
getPlayListVideos(listId: string) {
    return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + this.apiKey + '&fields=items/snippet/resourceId/videoId,items/snippet/publishedAt,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/thumbnails/high/url&playlistId=' + listId +'&part=snippet,id&maxResults=25')
    .map((res) => {
      return res.json()['items'].filter(item => {
        if(item.snippet.title === 'Private video'){
          return false;
        }
       });
    })
}
```

Comment: make sure you are filtering on an array and the array filter is only returning items that pass a boolean check that makes sure that the true items are not private. 

If you can give a sample of data I can construct the case you need to get what you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true if you don't want to filter the current item. Currently you're returning either false or undefined implicitly since you don't return anything in that case. So you need to do this:

```
if(item.snippet.title === 'Private video'){
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

or better yet `return item.snippet.title !== 'Private video'`.

Bonus formatting - I'd write the whole thing like this personally:

```
  getPlayListVideos(listId: string): any[] {
       return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + this.apiKey + '&fields=items/snippet/resourceId/videoId,items/snippet/publishedAt,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/thumbnails/high/url&playlistId=' + listId + '&part=snippet,id&maxResults=25')
              .map(res => res.json()['Items'])
              .map((items: any[]) => items.filter(item => item.snippet.title !== 'Private video'))
  }
```